# CSS2 Validation error with Gradient

Tags: validation, gradient, birt, css

The following is my CSS code:

```
table th{  font-family:arial; font-size:9pt;  color:#ffffff; background: -moz-linear-gradient(#b9cdde, #7c98ae);  border: 1px solid #ffffff; }

table th:last-child{  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#729cc3, #35699a); }
```

I get a validation error with CSS which says

> Value Error : background Too many values or values are not recognized : -moz-linear-gradient(#b9cdde,#7c98ae) -moz-linear-gradient(#b9cdde,#7c98ae)

Does someone have any idea as to why this might be happening?

Comment: gradients are css3 properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vendor-specific selectors such as `-moz-linear-gradient` are not part of the official CSS2 specification, so when the validator finds then, it will throw an error. Personally, I don't mind if stuff like this doesn't validate - it's only a nice, cleanly written gradient.

Comment: It seems rather strange that BIRT is that strict. I can't really look into it, but is there possibly a setting that turns off the strict-ness. As an alternative, you could use a repeated gradient image as the background. It's not ideal, but at least it would work.

Comment: Ya, I was considering that option as well. But there are a few other elements that are not being supported by the BIRT. One being this and the other being "last-child" property, both of which I am extensively using throughout. Turning off the strictness is an option that I would look into. Any other inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: BIRT has two ways to add CSS: "Import CSS" and "Use CSS". If you use HTML output only, then "Use CSS" with "Include CSS file at view time" option could be more powerful and it shouldn't be restricted to BIRT-supported properties.

Comment: @reg_frenzy: You could try using [PrefixFree](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree) – it's a client-side script that adds the prefixes for you based on the browser. So in your CSS you would simply use `background: linear-gradient(...)` and let PrefixFree add the prefixes for you.